# Is there a Gimap project ported to derive support from Jakarta Mail?

Tags: java, project, imap, libraries

There was a project "Gimap" - to build onto the javax.mail system to support some Google extensions to IMAP protocol.

This project can still be found here: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release (or https://github.com/javaee/javamail/tree/master/gimap )

The underlying project javax.mail was sent out from Oracle and into Jakarta, now found here: https://github.com/jakartaee/mail-api

but I don't think Gimap was taken along. Can someone describe what happened to that, and where's the best place to find something equivalent based on Jakarta or any other currently supported libraries?

Comment: The [commit log](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/commits/master) says 16 of the last 20 commits were by Bill Shannon, who was diagnosed with cancer just when the commits stopped and died some time later. He was a great guy, a **great guy.** Ordinary humans don't just take over the work of someone like him.

Comment: I'd suggest the gimap commit log is here: https://github.com/javaee/javamail/commits/master/gimap/src/main

Comment: the rest of the javamail project, to which Bill committed changes, was carried on here https://github.com/javaee/javamail/commits/master/gimap/src/main until release 2.1.1, just last week. So I'm not convinced the loss of Bill Shannon dissuaded other developers from continuing the work.